# How to compare & analyse performance of three servers running on my local machine?

Tags: performance, webserver, analysis

I want to compare and analyse the performance of three servers namely Cherokee, lighttpd and nginx running on my local linux machine (Fedora).

How do I write a script for this? Kindly also suggest tools available for performing such analysis, which gives reliable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone did it here, with Cherokee, Lighttpd, nginx and other web servers, by writting a wrapper around ApacheBench which outputs CSV files suitable or Charting:

/dsec.com/source/ab.c.txt

The ab.c program can be run with their program:
(under Linux)

gwan -r ab.c

The results can be seen there for Windows:

/dsec.com/en_windows.html

And Linux:

/dsec.com/en_linux.html

And Java, PHP and .Net:

/dsec.com/

It should sae you a lot of work to re-use their stuff.